# Is there any way to do a 'New Game+'?

Tags: custom-robo-arena

I beat Custom Robo a long, long time ago.  Unfortunately, once you beat it, there's not much to do buy walk around the town battling the same people over and over again.  Even worse, the game only has one save file.  I'd like a way to start over again, but I really don't want to lose my parts, or my dioramas (which I spent a great deal of time on).

If I start a new game, do I get to keep my stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there isn't a way to keep your stuff if you start all over again, however if you are able to use cheats you can turn on certain cheats that will give you all the parts and dioramas.

Comment: Argh, that's not what I wanted to hear.  It's not worth it then, I <3 my robo poses.  =[